# ng-route Under no load, page correctly

Tags: angularjs

i have a sub web and this no have head, body etc, contain only the content and im calling with ng-route and show with ng-view, but if i call the web without route eq. localhost/secondtab.html all work fine, but if i call with route and ngview, the script dont work here i put the code.

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute']);
        $url ="/load.php?stundent=<? echo $_GET["all"]; ?>";
           myApp.factory('myService',function($http){       
                     var getData = function() {
            return $http({method:"GET", url:$url}).then(function(result){
                return result.data;
            });
        };
        return { getData: getData };
    });


    myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl : 'main.html',
                    controller  : 'ItemsController'
                })
                // route for the home page
                .when('/one', {
                    templateUrl : 'one.html',
                    controller  : 'ItemsController'
                })

                // route for the about page
                .when('/two', {
                    templateUrl : 'p/two.html',
                    controller  : 'othercontroller'
                });
        });
    myApp.controller('othercontroller',  function othercontroller($scope,$http) {
    ...
    });

myApp.controller('ItemsController',  function ItemsController($scope,myService,$timeout,$http) { 
...
}
```

extract main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html  ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<head>
//load css
//load script(angularjs, routejs, jquery)
</head>
<body>
<a href="#one" target="_self" class="ng-binding">one</a>
<a href="#two" target="_self" class="ng-binding">two</a>
</body>
```

the one.html(this fail)

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       if(typeof Muse == "undefined") window.Muse = {}; window.Muse.assets = {"required":["jquery-1.8.3.min.js", "museutils.js", "webpro.js", "musewpslideshow.js", "jquery.museoverlay.js", "touchswipe.js", "jquery.musepolyfill.bgsize.js", "jquery.watch.js", "musewpdisclosure.js", "jquery.musemenu.js", "index.css"], "outOfDate":[]};
    </script>

      <!-- CSS -->
      .....
      <!-- Other scripts -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
       document.documentElement.className += ' js';
    </script>
      <!-- JS includes -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="scripts/html5shiv.js?4241844378" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <![endif]-->

  //content
     .......
     here a accordion menu
     //content

    <script type="text/javascript">
       if (document.location.protocol != 'https:') document.write('\x3Cscript src="http://musecdn2.businesscatalyst.com/scripts/4.0/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
    </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       window.jQuery || document.write('\x3Cscript src="p/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
    </script>
```

please help me